# How do I calculate the area of a projection created by the command "view"?

Tags: matlab, plot, view, projection, map-projections

How do I calculate the area of a projection? For example, using the following code, I get a projection on the X-Z plane.

```
[x,y,z]=peaks;
surf(x,y,z);
xlabel('x');ylabel('y');zlabel('z')
view([0,0])
```

[X-Z Plane Projection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQWQY.jpg)

I want to be able to determine the area of the projection of any surf plot that I create. Is there a command or function for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**

```
polyarea(x(1,:),max(z))+polyarea(x(1,:),min(z))
```

**Explanation**

The plot you want to calculate its area is,

[image]

In area calculation you need only the borders of the projection,

```
plot(x(1,:),max(z))
hold on
plot(x(1,:),min(z),'r')
```

and the output is,

[image]

The total area is the summation of both areas (upper border to x axis and lower border to x axis),

```
>> polyarea(x(1,:),max(z))+polyarea(x(1,:),min(z))
>> 28.5947
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I fix this? my coordinates are not matrices
A=[-100 -40 50
-100 -40 0
-120 -40 50
-120 -40 0
-100 5 0
-100 5 50
-120 5 50
-120 5 0
-100 0 52
-100 0 52
20 0 5
20 0 5
-100 50 5
-100 50 5
20 50 52
20 50 52
-30 70 53
-30 70 0
5 70 0
5 70 53
-30 120 53
-30 120 0
5 120 53
5 120 0];
theta=60;
rota = [cosd(theta) -sind(theta) 0; sind(theta) cosd(theta) 0; 0 0 1]; 
R=A*rota;
x=R(:,1);
y=R(:,2);
z=R(:,3);
surf(x,y,z)
polyarea(x(1,:),max(z))+polyarea(x(1,:),min(z))

Comment: You have problem in A matrix dimension.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the projection area at an arbitrary view angle, you can use the `viewmtx` function to project the surface onto the viewing plane, and then use `boundary` and `polyarea` to extract the boundary and calculate the area. Something like this:

```
 % draw your surface
 [x,y,z]=peaks;
 surf(x,y,z);
 xlabel('x');ylabel('y');zlabel('z')
 axis equal;
 %extract the viewing angle, and calculate the resulting transformation matrix
 [az,el]=view(gca);
 T= viewmtx(az,el);
 % transform the surface points by this transformation matrix
 pts= [x(:),y(:),z(:),ones(numel(x),1)]';
 tpts= T*pts;
 tpts=(tpts(1:3,:))';
 % now "tpts" has the surface points projected onto the viewing plane
 figure, plot( tpts(:,1), tpts(:,2), 'bo'); axis equal;
 % calculate the border of this region, and calculate its area.
 border = boundary(tpts(:,1), tpts(:,2));
 projectedArea = polyarea(tpts(border,1), tpts(border,2));
```

This approach is based off of the help for [viewmtx](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/viewmtx.html).